# Looking for a short story that involves two individuals on a different planet, they encounter a black cube(?), which has inhabitants inside

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Not sure the specifics, but everything the title says has what I knew of the story. I think they took a peek into this black shape, and discovered there was things living inside, but they were doing something that made the two people repulse, not sure. It was written to be unnerving though.